# Django upload limits

Tags: python, django

I want to make've limited the number of users on the upload file. For example: 
Every day, users are limited to 1 image file.

**Views**

```
class Upload(views.LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
model = Posts
form_class = UploadForm
template_name = 'icerik_yukle.html'

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.author= self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return super(Upload, self).form_valid(form)
```

**Models**

```
class Gonderi(models.Model):
    author= models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="gonderi")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=10, default=id_olustur)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=yukleme_adresi, blank=True)
    subject= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    descrip = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    category= models.ForeignKey(Kategori, verbose_name="Kategori")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Göster', default=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if exists a record for the current day and if it has a valid picture for the user. If there is, raise an exception

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    from datetime import datetime
    query = Gonderi.objects.filter(created__date=datetime.now().date(),
                                   author=request.user)
    instance = query[0] if query.count() > 0 else None
    if instance and instance.image:
        #raise your error over here


    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.author= self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return super(Upload, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I tried the code but did not work. Upload can be done without limit.

Comment: @SaadettinYasirAKEL are u rising the exception ?

Comment: I have tried in this way. I'm sorry for the novice. `    def form_valid(self, form):
        sorgu = Gonderi.objects.filter(olusturma_zamani=datetime.now().date(),
                                       sanatci=self.request.user)
        instance = sorgu[0] if sorgu.count() > 0 else None
        if instance and instance.resim:
            raise Exception("Günlük limitiniz doldu.")
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.sanatci = self.request.user
        self.object.save()`